# How to run the schedule every five minutes in Logstash 5.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-5, logstash-jdbc

I'm having a `jdbc` connection within my `input` in `logstash` where as I'm trying to execute the query according to the `schedule` property. I went through [jdbc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) and [rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler), but still pretty unclear of what those five stars(*) represent individually.

As per my knowledge, the stars from left to right (* * * * *):

1. minute
2. hour
3. from (month)
4. to (month)
5. day

So if it's a scenario as such (* * * * *), it represents that the scheduler would run every minute. Hence if I'm to run it every five minutes, how the scheduler should look like? Something like (5 * * * *)?

Have I assumed it right? Or correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Adding to @Val's answer, [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/cron-every-5-minutes/) could be helpful as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`5 * * * *` will run it only once per hour, five minutes after the hour, i.e. at HH:05

If you want to run it every five minutes of every hour, you need to write the schedule like this:

```
*/5 * * * *
```

Comment: So if I'm using `every` on something, I should be having the slash (/) in front of it?

Comment: It depends, but mostly yes. You might want to specify every 15 minutes but only from 10 minutes onwards, you'd then specify like this `10,25,40,55 * * * *` instead of `*/15 * * * *`

Comment: Every five minutes can also be specified like this `0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *` but it's longer

Comment: true that. If the minutes are bigger, it's better to go with `10,25,40,55 * * * *` and if the minutes are relatively less, can go with */5 * * * *

Comment: No, it has more to do with the starting point, if you start at 0 minutes, then `*/x * * * *` is the way to go, otherwise you need to specify where you start and enumerate each single minute you want to trigger your job.

Comment: Thank you so much. Noted :)